# Swift cast AnyObject to protocol and assign property

Tags: ios, swift, dependency-injection

I am trying to solve a dependency in Swift using an external injector like this:

```
class DependencyInjector {
    var networkManager:NetworkQueueManager

    protocol InjectorDelegateNetworkQueue{
        var networkManager:NetworkQueueManager {get set}
    }

    func injectDependencies(object:AnyObject){
            if object is InjectorDelegateNetworkQueue{
                object.networkManager = networkManager
            }
    }
}
```

Obviously, this won't work since `AnyObject` does not have a property called `networkManager`, only the cast object has one.
I mean to call this method inside the init method of other classes, by calling

```
DependencyInjector.sharedInstance().injectDependencies(self)
```

How can I get this to work in Swift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can maybe go like:

```
func injectDependencies(object:AnyObject){
        var thing:InjectorDelegateNetworkQueue? = object as? InjectorDelegateNetworkQueue
        if thing {
            thing.networkManager = networkManager
        }
}
```

Comment: just did this off the top of my head, probably a nicer way to in-line it in the if statement

Answer (score 0):

Change your func to this.

```
func injectDependencies(object:AnyObject){
        if object is InjectorDelegateNetworkQueue{
            (object as InjectorDelegateNetworkQueue).networkManager = networkManager
        }
}
```